# Como verificar a quantidade de objeto em um array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uma requisição ajax, o qual retorna um array de objetos (data), como eu faria pra fazer uma verificação sobre a quantidade desses objetos?

Exemplo:

```
Se (data retornar mais de um objeto no array){
    faça isso
    }senão{
    faça isso
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
if (minha_array.length > 0) {
  //true
} else {
  //false
}
```